# Can't bind to 'Property X' since it isn't a known property of 'Child Component'

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, angular-components

In my project I have a generic class and some other components which inherited from that.

**BaseRdnInput.ts:**

```
   @Injectable()
    export abstract class BaseRdnInput implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
    
      @Input() rdnModel?: any | Array<any>;
      @Output() rdnModelChange: EventEmitter<any | Array<any>> = new EventEmitter<any | Array<any>>();
      // many code after...
    }
```

**RdnInputComponent.ts:**

```
@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'rdn-input',
  templateUrl: './rdn-input.component.html'
})
export class RdnInputComponent extends BaseRdnInput implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
 // many code after...
constructor(public changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super(changeDetectorRef);
  };
// many code after
}
```

Then I am using this component in **ContractComponent.html:**

```
<rdn-input [(rdnModel)]='headerEntity.saleNo'></rdn-input>
```

By this line of code I get this error :

> Can't bind to 'rdnModel' since it isn't a known property of
> 'rdn-input'.
>
> 1. If 'rdn-input' is an Angular component and it has 'rdnModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'rdn-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
> 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

It was working fine before I upgrading. My question is very similar to this one: Angular2 RC5: [Can't bind to 'Property X' since it isn't a known property of 'Child Component'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960141/angular2-rc5-cant-bind-to-property-x-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-chi). I got that there are some setps to avoid this error and the most important is:
checking if we add @input to the property of sub class or adding attr to the biding property of parent.
if you see I have already added `@input` in **BaseRdnInput.ts:**. and I don't want to use attr because it will stop that property from being passed down to nested directives. Is there anyway to pass this?

Comment: What happens when you change your super class decorator to @Directive ?

Comment: @MikeOne why should I do that? how I do that?

Comment: You don't need the `@Injectable()` on an abstract class

Comment: You need a decorator with newer versions Angular if you want to use things like Input or @Hostbinding.

Comment: Eshgi simply replace the Injectable decorator with @Directive

Comment: @MikeOne  the reason why I add injectable is this error : Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator so I should use component or directive as your recommendation or injectable. However, I changed it to directive, but error not vanished...

Comment: Worth a try... maybe a module issue? Is this component declared correctly in a module and is the module itself imported correctly?

Comment: @MikeOne yes, be sure , it is working when use ng serve. but in normal way I got this error, I even checked if I added formmodule to  module, is that somthing related to inheritance ?

Comment: @MikeOne I was thinking if I have to add something to supper() , may it doesn't understand input of parent

Comment: Shouldn’t be. I use this quite a lot (but with Component or Directive, never with Injectable)

Comment: "_It was working fine before I upgrading_" - what was the previous version, and what is the current version?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the one who wrote the accepted answer on the question you linked. Haven't worked with Angular in a looong time so bear with me, but I did some troubleshooting and possibly figured it out.

It's definitely an inheritance thing. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41979236/5386466) answer to a relevant question:

> If a class inherits from a parent class and does not declare a constructor, it inherits the parent class constructor, and with it the parameter metadata of that parent class.

Because `RdnInputComponent` defines its own constructor, it's not inheriting the decorator metadata of the base class. If you remove the constructor, it then complains that `BaseRdnInput` doesn't have its own decorator and suggests, as did @Yngve B-Nilsen, adding `@Directive()`. That appears to fix the issue whether `RdnInputComponent` has a constructor or not (see this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-refvsq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)).

Alternatively, just adding the inherited binded properties to `inputs` and `outputs` of the `RdnInputComponent` metadata seems to work as well ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-af8npe?file=src/app/app.component.ts)), like so:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'rdn-input',
  templateUrl: './rdn-input.component.html',
  inputs: ['rdnModel'],
  outputs: ['rdnModelChange']
})
export class RdnInputComponent extends BaseRdnInput {
// ...
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate your base class with `@Directive()` - not `@Injectable`

Comment: I have already told this in comments, I changed it, but there is no difference.